# pagination and filtering is not stable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filtering, ngtable

I have an dynamic table that shows data from users array.And i want to filter according to all fields and they are not specific, they are depend on users array. Also users array can  change too.

```js
 $scope.usersTable = new ngTableParams({
   page: 1,
   count: 10
 }, {
   total: $scope.users.length,
   getData: function($defer, params) {
     debugger;

     $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.users, params.orderBy()) : $scope.users;
     $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.users, params.filter()) : $scope.users; // in there this data must be filtered but it is not
     params.total($scope.data.length);

     $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
     $defer.resolve($scope.data);
   }
 });
 $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.users[0]);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="src_product " placeholder="Aramak İstediğiniz Ürün Alanını Giriniz" ng-model="src_product" ng-change="getProducts()">

<table ng-table="usersTable" id="productTable" class="table table-striped" show-filter="true">

  <tr>
    <th class=" bg-aqua-gradient  text-center" ng-repeat="column in cols">{{column}}</th>
    <th class="bg-aqua-gradient ">Adet</th>
  </tr>

  <tbody ng-form="labelPrintTableForm">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data  | filter: src_product">

      <td class="highlighted" id="{{row.id}}_{{column}}" ng-class="{'unhighlighted':unselectedCells.indexOf(row.id + '_' + column) != -1}" ng-repeat="column in cols" onclick=" selectcells(this)">
        {{row[column]}}
      </td>
      <td class="highlighted">
        <input class=" input-group-sm " type="number" style="width: 100%; height: 30px !important" name=" adet" value="0" ng-minlength="0" required>
        <span ng-show="labelPrintTableForm.adet.$error.required">Adet alanı En az 0 olar</span>
      </td>


    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

this is not doing filtering. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: well you can use angular smart table.. its very easy

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.I write

```
 `$scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.users, $scope.src_product) : $scope.users;`
```

instead of

```
$scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.users, params.filter()) : $scope.users;
```